# Python for .NET compilation for .NET3.5 and Python3.x

Tags: python, .net, python-3.x, .net-3.5, python.net

Recently I've been working on a project which needs to use a `.NET 3.5` Dll library, and the team is using Python3.x environment.

So I went to the [Python for .NET's github repo](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/releases) and downloaded the source code and tried compiling myself using Visual Studio 2013.

In the source, there is a MVSC solution file named `pythonnet`, and I just opened the project and tried compiling `Python.Runtime`.

By default, the `Conditional compilation symbols` is `PYTHON27, UCS4`. So I changed it to `PYTHON35, UCS2` to match my requirement. And I was able to compile it successfully. 
[image: python35]

But since it needs to work with `.NET Framework 3.5`, then I changed `Target Framework` from `.NET Framework 4.0` to `.NET Framework 3.5`. But this time I got a lot of errors when compiling and the compilation failed.[image: DotNET3.5]

Could anyone please help me with the compilation so that I can compile the **Python for .NET** which works for both **.NET 3.5** and **Python3.x**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Latest pythonnet is using `HashSet` from CLR 4.0 and also `dynamic` from DLR which cannot be easily backported to older .NET versions.

What you can do is redirect your other DLLs from .NET 3.5 to CLR 4.0 using app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! But the problem is my other DLLs are provided by third-party, which means I don't have the source code for it. Is there a way I can convert?

Comment: You can just reference your 3rd party .NET 2.0 dlls from Visual Studio project that is configured for .NET 4.0. I do this all the time!

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick response. But I'm directly using the DLL from Python by Pythonnet, no Visual Studio project involved.. I don't quite understand what you mean..

Comment: If you are directly using 3rd party .NET 3.5 dll from python using pythonnet, then app.config should be placed next to python executable - python.exe.config - this is different exe if you use ipython, ptipython, etc.